# I need to call an object from an other class in my application of JAVA

Tags: java

I am trying to learn Java. I designed an application about a "Student Information System" and I need your help.

I created a List and I stored new student information there with class of `NewStudentScreen`.
Now I need to show this student information at class of `AskStudentScreen`.

The class in which I take student information is `NewStudentScreen`:

```
public void showMainScreen() {

    System.out.print("studentName: ");
    String studentName = GeneralUtil.readConsole();
    System.out.print("studentSurname: ");
    String studentSurname = GeneralUtil.readConsole();
    System.out.print("studentNumber: ");
    String studentNumber = GeneralUtil.readConsole();
    System.out.print("departmentName: ");
    String departmentName = GeneralUtil.readConsole();     
    System.out.print("studentAddress: ");
    String studentAddress = GeneralUtil.readConsole();
    System.out.print("studentTelephone: ");
    String studentTelephone = GeneralUtil.readConsole();

    Student student = new Student();

    student.setName(studentName);
    student.setSurname(studentSurname);
    student.setNumber(studentNumber);
    student.setAddress(studentAddress);
    student.setTelephone(studentTelephone);

    student.setDepartment(student);

    Config.getStudents().add(student);

    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println(student.getName() +" "+student.getSurname()+ " is created.");
    GeneralUtil.readConsole();
    getApplication().gotoMenu(0);
```

And the class in which I asked for new students' info is `AskStudentScreen`

```
public void showMainScreen() {

     System.out.println("Number of created student is : " + Config.getStudents().size());

    System.out.print("Enter searched students' number: ");
    String ögNo= GeneralUtil.readConsole();


    if(Config.getStudents().contains(ögNo)){
        System.out.println(ögNo+ " found in system. ");
    }
    else
        System.out.println("Student couldn't found.");
```

I tried everything but I always get "Student couldn't found."

Full source can be found on [github](https://github.com/Selman01/Superior/tree/master).

Comment: Where are the names of your classes and have you created any class or not?

Comment: Post the full code here!.

Comment: What is Config.getStudents() returning?

Comment: We need to see your `Student` class. Regardless, it looks suspicious to me that you are using `contains` to search a list of type `Student` for an object of type `String`. Chances are you need to make a `equals` method in your `Student` class that returns true if the name you read from the console matches the name of the student. We also need to see how you create whatever data structure is returned by your `getStudents` method.

Comment: @Fredk i think `Config.getStudents()` must be returning `list`

Comment: @AsteriskNinja  yeah  its returning  list of students

Comment: @FallAndLearn I did with a new answer.

Comment: @VatsalSura I uploaded full code at new answer. You can check friend, thanks.

Comment: @S.C. yeah I uploaded all code at new answer friend check it please, thanks.

Comment: So you really don't see how much nonsense it is to post an update to your question as an answer? Really? What do you think is the purpose of the [edit] link under the question?

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comment, your `AskStudent` screen is looking through a list of `Student` objects for a `String` object. This is going to fail because those types are incomparable. Furthermore, you cannot just add an `equals` and `hashCode` override to your `Student` class because `contains` uses the `equals` and `hashCode` methods of the search parameter type (`String` in your case), so they won't be used. Instead, change your `AskStudent` check from this:

```
if(Config.getStudents().contains(ögNo)){
    System.out.println(ögNo+ " found in system. ");
}
else
    System.out.println("Student couldn't found.");
```

to this:

```
    Student match = Config.getStudents().stream().filter(s -> s.getNumber().equals(ögNo)).findFirst().orElse(null);
    if(match != null){
        System.out.println(ögNo+ " is found: " + match.getName());
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Student doesn't found.");
    }
```

Now it checks the number of each `Student` in the list against the number passed in. This assumes that each student number will be unique.

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help! If you wouldn't mind accepting and/or upvoting this answer so others can more readily find it useful in the future as well, I would appreciate it.

Comment: @superior, Please comment something sensible! StackOverflow is a professional Q&A site!!

Comment: There's nothing wrong with happiness expressed professionally. You can still show happiness with only words that can be found as they are spelled in the dictionary and using only one punctuation character where one will suffice. You are young in  your technical ventures and @JavaHopper is just trying to help you recognize how you are situating yourself to be perceived by technical communities like this one.

Comment: @superior, "No" for finding an answer. But, the comments we leave here should not be funky or some sort of english we usually use in texting. You are free to use jargon. All this effort is just to make this SO community a better place so that other users don't have difficulty figuring out actual content rather than being lost in between some discussions that aren't really helpful. I hope you understand :)

Comment: @JavaHopper what a long answer. Thanks for your effort im gonna be more careful